# Push Notifications does not work in iOS 9 and later

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, notifications

I have a problem with Push Notifications in iOS. I have followed-up [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started/) tutorial. Push notifications have not been received in iOS 9 and later.

this is the code for registration and manage notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:HUBLISTENACCESS
                                                             notificationHubPath:HUBNAME];

    [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError* error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
            [self MessageBox:@"Registration Error" message:[error localizedDescription]];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Registering for notifications OK");
            [self MessageBox:@"Registration Status" message:@"Registered"];
        }
    }];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotificationError object:error];
    [self MessageBox:@"Registration Status" message:[error localizedDescription]];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    [self MessageBox:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"] message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]];
}

-(void)MessageBox:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)messageText
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:messageText delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

And I have checked Push Notifications and Remote Notifications (in Backgorund Modes) in Capabilities

Thanks in advance

Comment: define: "Push notifications have not been received in iOS 9 and later" Do you see the log `Registering for notifications OK`? How are you sending the message to APNS? What is APNS response when you send, is it successfully or an error?

Comment: Hi @FelipeSabino and thanks for answering. Registering for notifications is OK. I am sending the message to APNS in "Azure Notification Hub Console" and it response successfully (it works in iOS 8). When I say that Notifications are not being received in iOS9 I mean that They are not appear on iPhone device(real device not xCode emulator)